# Jira release just an expedite issue

Tags: kanban, jira

I am using Kanban methodology in Jira to manage the workflow of a 'mature' project.
We can do deployments to production on Thursdays, so we accumulate stories in the 'Ready For Production' column until they go in a release, and then, after they are deployed, we hit the 'Release' button and create a new version.
However, if, let's say we're on a Monday and something needs to be released urgently and we create an expedite swimlane, is there any way to release just that and not the other non-expedite tasks that are due to be released on Thursday?

[image]

Comment: How are you using the Jira fixVersion field in this workflow? You may need to look at the integration between Jira and your deployment tool(s), but if you release a specific version, you may be able to take advantage of the fixVersion field. You may also be able to take advantage of links between issues and deployments in your tools. But without knowing more about your integrations and how you are integrating your source control and deployment tools with Jira, it's hard to say.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I am not integrating Jira and my deployment tool. And I am not using the fixversion field. How could I take advantage of that field for splitting releases?

Comment: @JaviTorre, how do you deal with the occasional story that was started but could not be (properly) finished before the release on Thursday? For example, work was started on Wednesday with the expectation to finish on time, but something happened and that expectation could not be met and the work is at best half finished.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau it remains in the 'In Development' column and not included for that release.

Comment: If you aren't using the fixVersion field. then I don't understand what "Release" button you are hitting. The notion of a release is tied to the Version pages and the fixVersion field. How are you associating issues with releases if not the fixVersion field?

Comment: @ThomasOwens in the last column of the kanban board there is a green button 'Create and release a version from this column'. Every week I hit that button and create a new release. Any help on what am I doing wrong and could I improve is very welcome.

Comment: @JaviTorre I don't think that's native Jira functionality. I've never seen anything like that before. You may be using a plugin that is creating Versions, assigning a fixVersion to issues, and/or marking Versions as released. Alternatively, this plugin could be using its own data under the hood in some way. Without knowing the plugins and integrations that you are using, it's hard to say what the best approach is.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I am not using any plugins, I am using a Kanban software project in Jira. I have added a screenshot of the button.

Comment: @JaviTorre Ah. I just poked around the docs and config - looks like someone turned that off in my instance, but I found it [in the docs](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/deploy-a-release/#Releasing-via-a-Kanban-board-in-a-company-managed-project). I think I can write an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[When you click the "Release" button on a company-managed Kanban board](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/deploy-a-release/#Releasing-via-a-Kanban-board-in-a-company-managed-project), you are choosing from a list of versions that are allocated to issues in that column. When you don't have versions assigned to those issues, you would be releasing all of them.

If you set the Fix Version field in those issues appropriately, you will be able to release one version and mark the issues associated with that version as Released. It's not clear what happens if you have some issues with a manually set Fix Version and others with no Fix Version, so you may need to explicitly set the Fix Version of all of the issues in the column.

I would also recommend looking at your issue workflow in general and consider setting the Fix Version field in advance. You can unlock some good visualizations of progress toward a version and make sure the work that you expect to release is on track for completion throughout the development process.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I can mark an issue with a fix version that is already released, when moving it to the 'done' column, it will disappear from there, won't it?

Comment: @JaviTorre You may want to experiment with that a bit. It depends on how you have your Kanban board sub-filter set up (I have mine set to only include work in unreleased versions or an empty fix version, for example) or other configurations. There's quite a bit that plays off of the different configs - the states mapped to each column, your board queries, and a couple of other things.